# Hive error exporting data as BSON object

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, hive

I am trying to create table (CTAS) from hive and want to write the file in BSON format, inorder to import it into MongoDb. 
Here is my query:

```
create table if not exists rank_locn
ROW FORMAT SERDE "com.mongodb.hadoop.hive.BSONSerde" 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT "com.mongodb.hadoop.BSONFileInputFormat"
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
as
select RGN_OVRHD_NBR,DM_OVRHD_NBR,LOCN_NBR,Derived,
rank() OVER (ORDER BY DERIVED DESC) as NationalRnk,
rank() OVER (PARTITION BY RGN_OVRHD_NBR ORDER BY DERIVED DESC) as RegionRnk,
rank() OVER (PARTITION BY DM_OVRHD_NBR ORDER BY DERIVED DESC) as DistrictRnk
from Locn_Dim_Values
where Derived between -999999 and 999999;
```

Three jobs are launched. The last reduce job is failing. Error log is as follows:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row (tag=0) {"key":{"reducesinkkey0":78133,"reducesinkkey1":143.82632293080053},"value":{"_col0":1,"_col1":12,"_col2":79233,"_col3":78133,"_col4":1634,"_col5":143.82632293080053},"alias":0}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:274)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:522)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:421)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row (tag=0) {"key":{"reducesinkkey0":78133,"reducesinkkey1":143.82632293080053},"value":{"_col0":1,"_col1":12,"_col2":79233,"_col3":78133,"_col4":1634,"_col5":143.82632293080053},"alias":0}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:262)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat$1.write(HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.processOp(FileSinkOperator.java:637)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.process(Operator.java:502)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:832)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.processOp(SelectOperator.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.process(Operator.java:502)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:832)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.PTFOperator.executeWindowExprs(PTFOperator.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.PTFOperator.processInputPartition(PTFOperator.java:198)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.PTFOperator.processOp(PTFOperator.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.process(Operator.java:502)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:832)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExtractOperator.processOp(ExtractOperator.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.process(Operator.java:502)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:253)
    ... 7 more
```

Please help me resolve the issue.

Comment: The issue seems to be with SERDE, but I am not able to figure what is the exact issue.

Comment: Hi, have you figured this out? What's your hadoop version?

Comment: @Maziyar I am using Hadoop version 1.0.3 and Hive 0.11
This isn't resolved yet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Skandy. Same as me. I gave up on BSON and wanted to use JSON and only insert the result back into MongoDB. But this problem (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9648) hasn't come to production yet. Meanwhile I have no idea what to do with my BSON files.